# ¿Cuál es el error o por qué no funciona la conexión de Java a MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Java, utilizo el IDE NetBeans, en la cual se tiene que realizar una conexión y una consulta a una base de datos MySQL, la cual está alojada en un servidor externo, no local, para ello, tengo dos archivos y hago uso del JDBC:

MySQL:

```
package Data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MySQL {

    Connection conexion = null;
    Statement comando = null;
    ResultSet registro;

    public Connection MySQLConnect() {

        try {
            String servidor ="jdbc:mysql://sql301.epizy.com/epiz_22818523_SerialUni";
            String usuario = "epiz_22818523";
            String pass = "yPp77OOQzzuA";
            //Se inicia la conexión
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, usuario, pass);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            conexion = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            conexion = null;
        } finally {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión Exitosa");
        }

        return conexion;

    }

}
```

Test:

```
package Data;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main ( String [] args ){

        try {

            MySQL db = new MySQL();
            db.MySQLConnect();

            String Table = "Serials";

            String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + Table;

            db.comando = db.conexion.createStatement();
            db.registro = db.comando.executeQuery(Query);

            while ( db.registro.next() ) {

                System.out.println("ID: " + db.registro.getString(0) +
                        "\nNombre: " + db.registro.getString(1) +
                        "\nCorreo: " + db.registro.getString(2) +
                        "\nContraseña: " + db.registro.getString(3) + 
                        "\nSerial: " + db.registro.getString(4) + 
                        "\nBase: " + db.registro.getString(5));
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Cuando ejecuto la clase principal (Test) No me da ningún resultado, no muestra los datos y no muestra ni un JOptionPane.

¿Qué ocurre?

Comment: Analizando tu código pueden ser varias opciones, primero verifica si tu servidor acepta conexiones externas, verifica tu cadena de conexión falta el puerto, recuerda que el uso de finally en los bloques catch/try es para acciones que siempre van a pasar generalmente para regresar el programa a un punto seguro después de haber entrado a una excepción, es decir, el JOptionPanel debería ir en otro lugar. Haz intentato debugguear el programa?, la instancia de la base de datos si se crea?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Conexion {

    Connection c;

    public Conexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombrebd", "usuario", "contraseña");
            // puedes reemplazar localhost por la ip del servidor de base de datos o la url del servidor

            System.out.println("conectado");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c = null;
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```